# IllegalArgumentException is not being caught or missing something

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, illegalargumentexception, throws

The following code:

```
try {
    value = parse(myData);
} catch (Exception e) {
    if ( e instanceof IOException|| e instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
       logger.debug("illegal argument");
    } else {
       logger.debug("this is printing");
    }
}
```

Parse method:

```
parse(String data) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
   // do validation
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal");
}
```

I was expecting "Illegal argument". But instead it shows "this is printing".

Did I miss anything here?

Comment: should work, are you sure you're not running an old version of the application?

Comment: Same here, when copying the code into an empty project, it printed "illegal argument".

Comment: Nope. I can see the message "Illegal", which is thrown from parse. But its not being matched in if condition

Comment: Do a `getClass()` to check what you're getting.

Comment: You are right. Its throwing some other exception. Please put this as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: You're better off answering your own question. I was just commenting do get you started. You still haven't told us how/why.

Comment: When this IllegalArgumentException is thrown, its overridden by EJBTransactionException. Now the question is different, how not to have EJBTransactionException override the actual exception

Comment: @KevinRave Is that because of some AOP aspect? You can't really prevent it. But afaik, the EJBTTransactionException will have an inner `cause` exception that should be yours.

Answer (score 2):

I traced it. When this IllegalArgumentException is thrown, its wrapped by EJBTransactionRollbackException.

The following is thrown:

```
The transaction has been marked rollback only because the bean encountered a non-application 
exception :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Actual Exception class: class javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
```

Now the question is different, how not to have EJBTransactionException override the actual exception

Comment: Overriden is not then right word for this. The `EJBTransactionRollbackException` wraps the `IllegalArgumentException` and so the types don't match. You can just catch the exception and do `getCause()` to get yours.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. Are you sure you use classes from the same package on **throw** and **catch** sections. For example you can throw `com.foo.bar.IllegalArgumentException` in parse method but trying to catch `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`
So could you please check import section in case you have them in different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. IllegalArgumentException is wrapped by EJBTransactionRollbackException. I had same problem, when i use JsrValidator inside EJB Bean. This is happened because a RuntimeException was thrown inside EJB Bean, and AOP wraps it.If you too use EJB bean in parse method, try to add try-catch there.